# Exam class: answerspace for students same line in front of the question

Tags: exam

I'm a teacher and set question papers using the exam package. I want to type some text then `\fillwithdottedlines{0.25in}` as an example. How do I do this?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item feature 1 \fillwithdottedlines{0.25in}
\item feature 2 \fillwithdottedlines{0.25in}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item feature 1 \dotfill \newline\mbox{}\dotfill
\item feature 2 \dotfill \newline\mbox{}\dotfill
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]